# Unsuccessful XDebug installation

Tags: php, apache, installation, xdebug

I'm trying to install XDebug on my local machine with Win 7, Apache 2, PHP 5.3.6 TS VC9 build (server manually installed, no package). I've followed instructions at http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php:
I've downloaded dll, moved to dir with other extensions, added following code to C:\Windows\php.ini, restarted server and - in contrary to my expectations - xdebug is neither installed nor listed in phpinfo page.

```
zend_extension="E:\www\server\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll"
```

Altough I've gone trough my phpinfo and XDebug site several times I still have no idea what can cause this problem. Do you have any suggestions how to get XDebug working please?

Thank you

Comment: Have you check apache's logs?

Comment: greg0ire: Yes, I don't see anything suspicious here. I've restarted the server and this is new: http://pastebin.com/ExzxYvke

Comment: Did you enable xdebug in php.ini? `xdebug.default_enable=1`

Comment: According to documentation xdebug.default_enable has value 1 by default. Of course I've tried it, but it didn't help. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" the problem by updating from 5.3.6 to 5.3.8. I dont know where the problem was, but update and it will work fine. (I used http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php)

Answer (score 0):

According to netbeans manual you have to add the xdebug configuration file to the apache php ini directory and not the local php ini directory to make it work with anykind of wamp.
1) http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug
2) Definition of wamp: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP

Comment: As I have mentioned in my first post, I am not using WAMP ("server manually installed, no package"). Thanks anyway

Comment: I'm not using either but you use Windows.

Comment: Sorry, I thought of WAMP as of the concrete package with the this name, not in general. But I still have the problem, altough I have copied php.ini into windows/ folder, apache/bin/ folder and php/ folder.

Comment: I've even used PHPINIDir E:/.../apache/bin in my VirtualHosts settings (and it reflected into phpinfo), but still no result with xdebug. FYI I'm using Apache from http://www.apachelounge.com/

Comment: I'm using lighttpd with xdebug. But my xdebug isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

try zend_extension**_ts**=...
and the in a console fire php -m to see whats in. No need to restart server